# Why did Bartosz Tiedemann have a horrified look on his face when Silja Tiedemann gave birth to his child?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dark

In the German TV show *Dark*, Silja Tiedermann travels back in time to 1890 where she falls in love with Bartosz Tiedemann and gives birth to his child. However, in the scene where she successfully gives birth (not to be confused with the scene where she dies because of the miscarriage) and names him Hannoo, why did Bartosz have this concerned, borderline horrified, look on his face?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because he has just realized he is the father of [Noah](https://dark-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/Hanno_Tauber) (real name Hanno Tauber) who had recruited him in the year 2019 when he was a teenager in season 1 to help Sic Mundus. This mind-twisting realization would be shocking to anybody.

Although (my speculation), I do not remember a time when Bartosz found out about Noah's real name. His surprise was probably put in place for dramatic effect as we, the audience, would have also just found out about this twist at the same time. Although we can assume that maybe Jonas or some other traveler has mentioned it off-camera as they have been working together for many years at this point.

Comment: It's also possible that Jonas has spoken of "his friend Hanno" (while not mentioning that it's Noah - presumably intentionally hiding it). That would also trigger some kind of reaction when his son gets named Hanno as well (seemingly out of the blue, by Silja). So Bartosz doesn't necessarily need to know that Hanno and Noah are two names for the same person.